# SQL COUNT returns No Data when the result should be 0

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm stuck trying to make this SQL query return a count of 0 if the certain coindition isn't true.
Example: I've 2 tables:

**TABLE A:**

| timestamp | host | current_state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1638290800 | serverA | 0 |
| 1638290800 | serverB | 0 |
| 1638290770 | serverA | 0 |
| 1638290770 | serverB | 2 |

**TABLE B**

| host | location |
| --- | --- |
| serverA | Barcelona |
| serverB | New york |
| serverC | Barcelona |
| serverD | New york |

Now my SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT A.timestamp, Count(*)
FROM tableB as B
LEFT JOIN tableA A ON A.host = B.host
WHERE A.current_state != 0 AND B.location= 'Barcelona'
GROUP BY A.timestamp
```

How can I get the count of host with current state != 0 grouped by timestamp?

The result of my query is the following:

| timestamp | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1638290770 | 1 |

And I'd like something like:

| timestamp | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1638290800 | 0 |
| 1638290770 | 1 |

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? You've tagged your question with both.

Comment: A query shouldn't return zero if there is no data. The problem in my consideration is the missconcepting you have of a database. If no data means zero, is a condition that has to be in the business layer, not in the database layer. Or even more, in the view layer.

Comment: How do you get timestamp from no-data? Wich is the timestamp do you want?

Comment: Not sure how this works in any case with `tableA c` and `A.host = B.host`. Also your `TABLE A:` is missing the `host` column the values of which are in `current_state` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things to change from your very close attempt:

1. Move your where condition for `barcelona` into the `ON` for your join of that table instead. Otherwise your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` becomes an implicit `INNER JOIN`
2. Also instead of `Count(*)`, just grab the count for `b.host` where a NULL for that column won't figure into the count.
3. Lastly swap the order in which you are joining these tables. You want all values from `TableA` and only those from `TableB` that meet your criteria.

---

```
SELECT A.timestamp, Count(b.host)
FROM tableA as A
LEFT JOIN tableB as B ON A.host = B.host AND B.location= 'Barcelona'
WHERE A.current_state != 0 
GROUP BY A.timestamp
```

Comment: `WHERE A.current_state != 0` turns the outer join into an inner join

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't even see they have the order of the left join flipped from my assumptions. Corrected the sql and added more to explanation.

Comment: Thank you very very much! <3

Comment: Not sure how that query works with the example data: the only row of tableA where `current_state!=0` uses `serverB`, and `serverB` is in New York... When I run this query, all I get is one row with `1638290770, 0`. (The query in my answer also gives an incorrect result).

Comment: The only way I can get to the results required in the question is to use `A.current_state != 0` in the join condition (not in `WHERE`) and use `B.location != 'Barcelona'` (not equals). (That said, the point you're making in this answer are indeed correct.)

Comment: @Bruno You also must flip the ordering of the tables in the FROM clause. We want all results from `TableA` and only those that match both the `a.host = b.host` condition and that are in `location = 'Barcelona'` from the `TableB`. If you set up the tables in whatever rDBMS you are using and run this query as-is it should give you two rows, one with a count of 0.

Comment: I know, I'd done that in my answer before you'd fixed yours, but if you run your query with the test data provided in the question, it won't give you the results expected in the question. (To be fair, the query in my answer wasn't providing the expected results either before I edited it :-) )

Comment: Oh! gotcha. I can't imagine why it wouldn't work in it's current form or what difference adding the join condition in the ON clause would do. In fact, wouldn't that let in that 4th record of the first table (I guess it would still give 0, but it feels strange).

Comment: As a_horse_with_no_name commented (and xQbert on my answer), `WHERE A.current_state != 0` does indeed turn the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (effectively), so you only get one row as a result. But the rest of the problem is with the OP's test data: the only row in Table A where `current_state != 0` is `1638290770, serverB, 2`, but in Table B, `serverB` is in "New York", so that won't match `B.location = 'Barcelona'`. Essentially, we've been chasing something unachievable from this question unfortunately...

Comment: I agree. Given the test data and the restriction of `current_state != 0` this result is not achievable. To address the issue that horse brought up, the reversal of the tables in the FROM clause keeps the LEFT OUTER JOIN acting as a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but back to square one where the provided test data can't actually yield the result OP is after. I guess I must have pointed enough in the direction they were after though. I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a result row for every timestamp in Table A, whether there is a matching join entry in Table B or not, then Table A needs to be on the left on your `LEFT JOIN` (or use a `RIGHT JOIN`, less common):

```sql
SELECT A.timestamp, Count(B.*)
FROM tableA as A
LEFT JOIN tableB B
   ON A.host = B.host AND A.current_state != 0 AND B.location != 'Barcelona'
GROUP BY A.timestamp
```

Comment: Outer join is negated by where clause criteria  making results behave like an inner.